# how to jump between cscope search result in current split

Tags: vim, cscope

How can I jump to the next search `cscope` result in `vim` and open it in the currently active split? If I open `:cw`, the selected result will always open in the top-right split, which is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:cwindow` will open the quickfix list in a window (quickfix window) if there are results (Similar to `:copen`). You do not need to use the quickfix window at all in your case. You can simply go to the next quickfix item via `:cnext`.

For more help see:

```
:h quickfix
:h :cnext
:h :cw
:h :cprev
:h :cl
:h :cc
```